# How to send List of List of MultiPartFile through postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I have this API method

```
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> createProducts(@RequestPart @Valid ProductRequest productRequest, @RequestPart List<List<MultipartFile>> imageList) { }
```

and now I want to send imageList through postman how can I send

[image]

Comment: I think this would be `public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> createProducts(@RequestPart @Valid ProductRequest productRequest, @RequestPart List<MultipartFile> imageList1, @RequestPart List<MultipartFile> imageList2) { }`. If you do not know the number of imageList, you would need to work from the HttpRequest to get the parts

Comment: @grekier excatly the issue is I don't the know the number its not fixed

Comment: Can you show me the way how can I work with HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> createProducts(HttpServletRequest request) {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    Set set = multipartRequest.getFileMap().entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
        // me.getKey() will give you the parameter name
        // me.getValue() will give you the data (List<MultipartFile> probably)
        // handle files ...
    }
}
```